# Lily Surface Scraper issue

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, add-on, eevee-render-engine

I recently downloaded the Lily Surface Scraper add-on. I was excited to try it out. But when I got it working and tried to see to render preview, the hdri doesn't. However, when I remove the ground hdri, it shows. Can you help understand why I can't show the image with ground hdri node enabled?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: How can I attach it?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: Ok. Sending it to you in 10 mins.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=VXQpyNes" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VXQpyNes/)

Comment: is this what you want to see? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FloaP.jpg -> i had to take another HDRI because you didn't provide yours...but you can see the ground + hdri

Comment: yes that's perfect!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: äh...i didn't change anything from your file except i opened another pic for the hdri....i just rendered in cycles and got that

Comment: maybe try with another hdri ....which you download e.g. from hdri heaven...

Comment: ok, but it looks so much better than what I attempted :)

Comment: it's your work mate. I didn't do anything to it except changing that image...